# Is the new "bookmark" button just "favorite" button renamed?

Tags: support, bookmarks, bookmark

[image]

Just noticed a new change, familiar favorite button now read as Bookmark

Comment: Yep https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347558/favorites-are-now-known-as-bookmarks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are both the same thing, just renamed. I had a favorite on an old question and now it is a bookmark. They also made an [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347558/favorites-are-now-known-as-bookmarks) on it.